# SearchView error when i delete my text on EditText

Tags: java, android, searchview

I try to Implement `searchview` on my `RecyclerView` using `EditText`. It goes well until I try to delete all of my text on `EditText`. My app stops working.

I've tried to add some condition for what app must do when my Text is null:

*FragmentHome.java*

```
edSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

            }
        });
```

*Adapter.Java*

```
public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()||charString.equals("")||charString.equals(" ")) {
                    listpensiunFiltered = listpensiun;
                } else {
                    List<PensiunModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (PensiunModel row : listpensiun ) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getNamaKtp().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getNopen2().contains(charSequence)) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    listpensiunFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = listpensiunFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                listpensiunFiltered = (ArrayList<PensiunModel>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: In which line you're getting `exception`, while clearing text in `editText`

Comment: Inside `afterTextChanged` check if the text is not `null` like this: `if(s != null && !s.equals("")){adapter.getFilter().filter(s);}`

Comment: What type of error are you getting and what's the line producing it?

Comment: @SomerandomITboy i dont find any error on logcat

Comment: @HB. im tryin that code but it still not working

Comment: @Android no exception on Logcat

Comment: @Android i found that exeption 
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList 

at this line
listpensiunFiltered = (ArrayList<PensiunModel>) filterResults.values;


java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: @SomerandomITboy  at
listpensiunFiltered = (ArrayList<PensiunModel>) filterResults.values;

Comment: check `listpensiunFiltered ` declared as `List` or `ArrayList`, because of that you may get `ClassCastException'

Comment: @Android 'List'

Comment: @Android ah i found my mistake, thankyou